# How do I remove the history portion of an email body?

Tags: regex, string, text, email

I am building an application that will send, read, and respond to emails. The problem is that if an email is part of a thread, it is likely to contain history information. Unfortunately, there is no consistency in how history information is displayed (sometimes it's marked with arrows >>>> sometimes with a rule, etc.) so it's not easily found by regular expression.

I am currently using several regexs that solve many cases, and adding new ones as they arise. Is this the best way to handle the problem?

Does anyone have a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

In all honesty, there is no good way to handle this problem.  Most email systems have a default way of doing this.  Setting using regular expressions for the most common ones will get you pretty far because most email systems run on default settings for this.  But you have to understand that this can be customized very easily from one email server to another meaning that there is no one-size-fits-all solution.

But...if good enough is good enough, just keep doing what you're doing or don't use forwards/replies.